# Bulk insert with SQLAlchemy ORM and return primary keys

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert a list of dictionaries into a table using `bulk_save_objects` or `bulk_insert_mappings`. Is there any way I can get the list of objects with primary key for each entry?

```py
try:
    cycle_object_list = []
    for cycle in cycle_list:
        period = Period()
        for k, v in cycle.items():
            setattr(period, k, v)
        cycle_object_list.append(period)

    db.session.bulk_save_objects(cycle_object_list)
    db.session.commit()
    print(cycle_object_list)
except Exception:
    db.session.rollback()
    raise
finally:
    db.session.close()
```

I am expecting something like `[Period.49, Period.50, Period.51]`

But the actual result is [Period.None, Period.None, Period.None]

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=bulk_save#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_save_objects)

> The objects as given are not added to the session and no additional state is established on them, unless the return_defaults flag is also set, in which case primary key attributes and server-side default values will be populated.

So this might work:

```
try:
    cycle_object_list = []
    for cycle in cycle_list:
        period = Period()
        for k, v in cycle.items():
            setattr(period, k, v)
        cycle_object_list.append(period)

    db.session.bulk_save_objects(cycle_object_list, return_defaults=True)
    db.session.commit()
    print(cycle_object_list)
except Exception:
    db.session.rollback()
    raise
finally:
    db.session.close()
```

Comment: It worked for `bulk_save_objects`. What if I want to use `bulk_insert_mappings`? I have also created another question for that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763998/sqlalchemy-bulk-insert-mappings-doesnt-return-primary-keys

Comment: @Mrprofessor you can still find it in the docs: you have to use the same kwarg 
`return_defaults=True`
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html?highlight=bulk_insert_mappings#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.bulk_insert_mappings.params.return_defaults