# SQLAlchemy bulk_insert_mappings doesn't return primary keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to insert a list of dictionaries into a table using `bulk_insert_mappings`. Is there any way I can get the list of objects with primary key for each entry?

```py
cycle_list = [
    {
        "name": "cycle 1",
        "primary": True
    },
    {
        "name": "cycle 2",
        "primary": False
    },
]
try:
    x = db.session.bulk_insert_mappings(cycle_list, return_defaults=True)
    db.session.commit()
    print(x)
except Exception:
    db.session.rollback()
    raise
finally:
    db.session.close()
```

I am expecting something like `[Period.4, Period.5]`

But the actual result is `None`

This issue is linked with [Bulk insert with SQLAlchemy ORM and return primary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58756255/bulk-insert-with-sqlalchemy-orm-and-return-primary-keys/58757121#58757121)

Comment: It operates exactly like `Session.bulk_save_objects()` in that it mutates the dictionaries in `cycle_list` in place if needed, and somewhat traditionally Python methods that mutate their argument (or an object in place) return `None`.

Comment: Is there any way I can get the primary keys using this method `bulk_insert_mappings`

Comment: Read them from `cycle_list` after performing the bulk insert, if using `return_defaults=True`.